# jenkins git doesn't recognize subsequent push

Tags: git, jenkins, git-ftp

I'm trying to use Jenkins on our local git-server to automatically publish new commits to our FTP-Server using git-ftp.

The initial upload works, but all subsequent commits are ignored.

I added a Free Style project and in Source-Code-Management, I added the Repo-URL:

```
file:////Users/me/my_repository.git
```

The credentials are blank, since we're on the local filesystem.

I don't get any errors in the console-output.

In the build-setup, I issue the shell command to upload the changed files to my sftp-server:

```
git ftp push --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASS -b dev -vv --auto-init sftp://my.server.tld:22/home/jenkins-test/dev-branch
```

The initial upload is working perfectly. But as soon as I make changes and push them to the repository, Jenkins doesn't see them and claims everything is fine.

Any ideas?

[Edit]

I found out, that when I delete the initial files on the webserver and do another git ftp push (with `--auto-init`), old files are uploaded - and I have no idea where they come from.

The console-outpout says:

```
Building in workspace /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/deploy-test-dev
```

When I check the files in this directory, they are the ones with the changes made in the last commit. Alas, they aren't the ones that are being uploaded to the ftp-server.

Is there some kind of caching going on???

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing *Build Triggers* in the job configuration?

Because your repository is located on local file-system, you should probably use *Poll SCM* trigger or [FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin).

Comment: The build-trigger ain't the problem. I'm clicking the «build now»-button to make the build running (for now).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the push-command.

instead of

```
git ftp push --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASS -b dev -vv --auto-init sftp://my.server.tld:22/home/jenkins-test/dev-branch
```

I had to delete the -b dev (since there isn't any dev-branch after the checkout).

So this works

```
git ftp push --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASS -vv --auto-init sftp://my.server.tld:22/home/jenkins-test/dev-branch
```